# Proyecto Entity Framework ejecutado desde el Programador de tareas de Windows da error de ConnectionString

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, entity-framework, windows10

He hecho un pequeño proceso Windows en .Net 4.8 que se conecta a una BD en SQL Server mediante EntityFramework 6.

Si depuro el proyecto desde Visual Studio funciona perfectamente.
Si ejecuto el .exe que me genera funciona perfectamente.

Pero si creo una tarea programada con el Programador de tareas de Windows, siempre falla, y en el Visor de eventos de Windows loga lo siguiente:

```
Aplicación: ProcesoPrueba.exe
Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319
Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a una excepción no controlada.
Información de la excepción: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential, System.Object, System.String, System.Security.SecureString, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString, System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.String, Boolean, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderManager)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal ByRef)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   en System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>)
   en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Dispatch[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.__Canon, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>)
   en System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(System.Action)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()

Información de la excepción: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy, Boolean, Boolean)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass7[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<GetResults>b__5()
   en System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption>)
   en System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   en System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   en ProcesoPrueba.Program.CompruebaArticulosExistentes()
   en ProcesoPrueba.Program.CompruebaParametros(System.String[])
   en ProcesoPrueba.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

---

Este es el App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProcesoContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Proceso.csdl|res://*/Proceso.ssdl|res://*/Proceso.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Proceso;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

¿Alguien me puede arrojar un poco de luz?

Comment: Intenta cambiar la cadena de conexión por una no-generada por EF.

Comment: Da igual. Da error igualmente.

Comment: Vas a tener que mostrar el código que estás usando, me late que hay algún problema con las conexiones, ¿las estás cerrando adecuadamente?

Comment: Si, claro. Si cuando depuro o ejecuto el .exe funciona perfectamente. Es cuando en la tarea programada de Windows le dijo que ejecute el .exe. La conexión la abro con un using: `using (Context contexto = new Context())`. No tiene nada fuera de lo normal.